# Eagerly loading all paginated data with json type provider

Tags: f#, type-providers

Cosider an API which reply is always of this structure:

```
{
    "pagination": {
        "limit": int,
        "offset": int,
        "count": int,
        "total": int
    },
    "data": [
        {...some obj...}
    ]
}
```

So payloads differ only in structure of data objects.

Ideally I'd like to tell F# that all types built from samples have some common part - pagination info, so  I can have one generic method which reads all pages.

Is it possible, or do I have to extract `pagination` object and `data` array separately with two type providers? I see the benefit of having one provider per response body as it supports reading data from the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define two different provided types, one for parsing the pagination data and one for parsing the actual data, i.e. something like this:

```
type Pagination = JsonProvider<"""{ 
  "pagination": { "limit": 1, "offset": 2, 
    "count": 3, "total": 4 } 
  }""">
type OneDataType = JsonProvider<"""{
    "data": [ {"a": 1} ]
  }""">
```

If you want to avoid parsing the same JSON file twice (e.g. by calling `Pagination.Parse` and `OneDataType.Parse` on the same string), you can actually just parse the data once and then pass the parsed `JsonValue` to the other type:

```
let odt = OneDataType.Load("/some/file")
let pg = Pagination.Root(odt.JsonValue)
pg.Pagination.Count
```

If you wanted to do this with a single provided type, then you could define multiple different fields for the multiple different types of data - but you'd have to name those differently. You'd then need to do some fiddling to read the data correctly. I would not do this, because I find it confusing, but it would look something like this:

```
type AnyData = JsonProvider<"""{ 
  "pagination": { "limit": 1, "offset": 2,
      "count": 3, "total": 4 },
  "data": [],
  "one_data_type": [ {"a":1} ],
  "another_data_type": [ {"b":"xx" }]
}""">

let a = AnyData.Load("/some/file")
// Access pagination data
a.Pagination
// Access data as if it was OneDataType
let oneData = [| for d in a.Data -> 
  AnyData.OneDataType(d.JsonValue) |]
```